# AWS Boto - Start instance, Deploy Docker Image, Run and Terminate

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, boto3

I have a web crawler that is a Docker Image. I want to use boto to create an EC2 instance, deploy my crawler, run the crawler and then when it's done terminate the instance.

My current idea would be something like:

- Launch new EC2 instance with an AWS Image containing Docker.
- SSH in to the instance using something like Fabric and install the Docker Image.
- Use same SSH connection to run my command to start the crawler
- Make the Web Crawler delete its own instance on completion.

A few details:

- Do I really need to use a tool like Fabric to SSH in to my instance and run commands?
- How do I select the instance that a script is currently running on? The `self` instance if you like.
- Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: you can use userdata to run your scripts within the EC2 instance. To get the instance id, query the instance meta-data (`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`). You need to attach an IAM role to the EC2 instance with `ec2:TerminateInstances` permissions.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to create a simple HTTP API and directly call it. SSH-ing programmatically is usually awkward. Here is what I would do:

1. Implement HTTP endpoint for starting the crawler. You will need a framework to do that, for example something like Flask:

   ```
   from flask import Flask, request, Response

   # Initialize the Flask application
   app = Flask(__name__)

   @app.route('/api/start_crawler', methods=['POST'])
   def segmentation_endpoint():
       r = request
       # r is now the request object. You can use it to pass additional info
       # implement the starting of the crawler here

   # start flask app
   app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
   ```
2. Start the docker container at startup. To do that, add user data when starting the instance, e.g:
   `#!/bin/bash
   docker run -p 80:<PORT> <image>:<tag>`

You can now start the crawler whenever you want by calling the endpoint.

To delete the instance when stopping, you can get the instance id from `/latest/meta-data/instance-id` as mentioned in the comments and then use boto3, for example:

```
# Boto 3
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
ec2.instances.filter(InstanceIds=ids).terminate()
```

Comment: If I need to host a flask app on the instance at all times it means that I have to pay for the instance to be up and running for 24/7. The whole point is that I don't want to have it running at all times.

Or did I misunderstand you of where to place the flask app?

Comment: The idea here is to just use the flask app to start the crawler (it replaces SSH). You will still need another machine from which to start the EC2 instance (you are probably going to use yours). You can create the EC2 instance once and then export the configuration to JSON, then you can start the same type of instance again with AWS CLI.